# Why doesn't move_base depend on move_base_msgs

Tags: navigation, catkin, actionlib, move-base, move-base-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the `CMakeLists.txt` for `move_base` ([link](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/move_base/CMakeLists.txt)), why is there no mention of `move_base_msgs` ? I would expect to see something like:

```
`add_dependencies(move_base move_base_msgs_gencpp)`
```

and/or see `move_base_msgs` listed under `find_package COMPONENTS`

Without that, how is it able to include the following (automatically generated) header in `move_base.h`:

```
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
```

And how does `catkin` know to generate the `MoveBase.action` msgs and headers before building `move_base` ?

**Update**: A colleague figured out that it's related to whether the packages are built in isolation or not.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236706/why-doesn%27t-move_base-depend-on-move_base_msgs/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-15**:
Looks like a bug. Are you seeing errors related to this?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-15**:
+1, how about opening a github issue? https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues ?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-06-15**:
I do if I don't build in isolation (i.e. when not using `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin build`). Specifically, it cannot find the header file mentioned above. I'll open an issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened an issue ([ros-planning/navigation/#483](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/483)) where I also included my hypothesis as to why this only becomes a problem when building with `catkin_make` but not with `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin build`

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0